# Linux console blinking rate goes crazy - as if is accepting repeated key inputs

Tags: usb, console

Environment:

Embedded x86. Ubuntu. Linux 4.4.152.

Overall scope:

I'm in the process of upgrading from 3.2.69. I'm to the point where the kernel will boot and the init.d/inittab scripts run.

Issue:

On the console (via tty), the cursor will start to blink at a standard rate, and then slowly speed up until its blinking really fast. Then it will start to blink at the standard rate, repeating to the really fast blink rate.

If I happen to touch a key on the keyboard during the really fast blink rate, the keystroke will be repeated many, many times.

If I disconnect the keyboard from the USB connection, the blink rate behavior does not return to normal, but continues the fast/slow behavior.

This occurs on every other reboot - in that if I reboot the machine, the blink rate is normal, and I don't have any undesired key repeats. Reboot again? Back to the crazy blink rate behavior.

If I disable the EHCI driver, the blink rate stays at the normal rate, but then, I can't use the USB keyboard.

Realize that it could be almost anything, but this is not an issue with kernel 3.2.69 with essentially the same kernel configuration.

Thoughts on where I can start looking to track this issue down? Although I've been working with Linux systems for a long time, I'm not savvy at resolving Linux startup/kernel issues.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that it has to do with the 'video' parameter of the kernel boot command line. The issue goes away if I don't have the 'video' parameter listed. Go figure. I am not going to chase down why; can live without specifying the 'video' parameter.